# Launching Chrome Browser through Appium on Windows

Tags: appium, browser-automation

I am trying to launch Chrome Browser through Appium on Windows but keep getting the following error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.streamW3CProtocolParameters(ProtocolHandshake.java:238)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:158)
    at GoogleTest.main(GoogleTest.java:30)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Incomplete document
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.close(JsonWriter.java:559)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:121)
        ... 6 more
```

Using the following dependencies:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Connected to real android devicce...

Answer (score 2):

It got fixed for me when i added a gauava.jar dependency to my pom.xml, i used version 21. Try if that works for you.